# Time difference between times in this format hh:mm:sss

Tags: excel, function

How can I find time difference between times in this format hh:mm:ss:sss please?

Here's a sample of the data

```
16:08:09:903
16:08:09:919
16:08:09:935
16:08:09:966
16:08:09:997
16:08:10:028
```

Thank you

Comment: subtract the smaller from the larger?

Comment: excel doesn't like that because seconds are 3 digits not 2

Comment: Then we need a lot more information.  Like for starters, how can 60 seconds per minute be three digits?  Please [edit] the post and include more info, it would be helpful if you provided test data and expected output that encompasses your data.

Comment: No problem. A sample of the data can be found below
08:09:903
08:09:919
08:09:935
08:09:966
08:09:997
08:10:028

Comment: [EDIT] the post to include the data in tabular form not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,":",".",3)-SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3)
```

Then format the cells with a custom format of `hh:mm:ss.000`

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's brilliant thank you very much